# Currency formatting in C#

Tags: c#

I can make one string into a currency format but not the other. The purpose of the program is to calculate tax bracket amounts for 2014 and show the taxes required for a level of income and what you will take home.

```
private void calculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double income = double.Parse(taxInput.Text);
    taxOutput.Text = calculateTaxes(income);
    takeHome.Text = calculateTakeHome(taxOutput.Text, income);        
}

private string calculateTakeHome(string p, double income)
{
    double numOne = double.Parse(p);
    double outcome = income - numOne;
    return outcome.ToString("C2"); 

}

private string calculateTaxes(double income)
{
    double total;
    if (income > 406750)
    {
        total = bracketSeven(income);
    }
    else if (income > 405100)
    {
        total = bracketSix(income);
    }
    else if (income > 186350)
    {
        total = bracketFive(income);
    }
    else if (income > 89350)
    {
        total = bracketFour(income);
    }
    else if (income >36900)
    {
        total = bracketThree(income);
    }
    else if (income > 9075)
    {
        total = bracketTwo(income);
    }
    else
    {
        total = bracketOne(income);
    }
    return total.ToString();
}

private double bracketOne(double income)
{
    double tax = income * .1;
    return tax;
}

private double bracketTwo(double income)
{
    double tax = ((income - 9075) * .15) + 907.5;
    return tax;
}

private double bracketThree(double income)
{
    double tax = ((income - 36900) * .25) + 5081.25;
    return tax;
}

private double bracketFour(double income)
{
    double tax = ((income - 89350) * .28) + 18193.75;
    return tax;
}

private double bracketFive(double income)
{
    double tax = ((income - 186350) * .33) + 45353.75;
    return tax;
}

private double bracketSix(double income)
{
    double tax = ((income - 405100) * .35) + 117541.25;
    return tax;
}

private double bracketSeven(double income)
{
    double tax = ((income - 406750) * .396) + 118188.75;
    return tax;
}
```

I am able to show takeHome.Text in currency format using `return outcome.ToString("C2")` but when I put "C2" into the calculateTaxes() function like so: `return total.ToString("C2");` I get an error saying that my parsing is incorrect. The program compiles but throws an exception when I try the calculation.

I have tried to parse it with "C2" in about 5 other ways and it still throws the same exception, any ideas?

Comment: What is the exception? Why do you use double for money when `Decimal` is made for that?

Comment: The exception is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format." @GabrielGM

Comment: Also, I changed it to `double` because of this issue, thought it might help, but nope.

Comment: What is the value of `p` you pass to `calculateTakeHome()`?

Comment: Is it always throws exceptions or only with specific values? Have you tried simple "C" as format?

Comment: The value passed to p is in the first method, `takeHome.Text = calculateTakeHome(taxOutput.Text, income);` taxOutput.Text. @Szymon

Comment: @JleruOHeP I have tried just "C" as well. What is happening is that the value is being passed through too many methods and functions so when I change it to currency ("C2") it messes up the `double` needed for calculation elsewhere. It's a headache. I appreciate the comments though!

Comment: So, what I need is to know how/where to apply the currency format so that it does not mess up the other calculations and throw an exception.

Comment: You can return double (decimal) from your calculate... methods and format them to string only when you are populating your controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to parse a string as double with the currency symbol. You can do this by using formatting. For example you can try something like below

```
    private static string calculateTakeHome(string p, double income)
    {
        double numOne = double.Parse(p,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency);
        double outcome = income - numOne;
        return outcome.ToString("C2");

    }
```

Comment: So, just for clarification, is the `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency);` only able to parse `double` into currency format? Or what other data types does it work on?

Comment: No. You get it with int, float etc